# Is there better way to create directory from string? cpp, create directory, stringstream, string.

Tags: c++, string, directory, stringstream

My code is working but I think it is awful way to do it. (Using system() has a security issues, and also creating string just because ss.str() is not accepted). Do you know any better way?

```
    stringstream ss;
    string dir;

    // make dir output
    ss.str(""); // set  empty
    ss.clear(); // clear bit flags
    ss << "mkdir \"" << argv[2] << "\"";
    dir = ss.str();
    system(dir.c_str());
```

argv[2] is from: int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {...

Any better ideas?

Comment: Try boost::filesystem

Comment: There is no standard way to create a directory. In Windwos we are using `CreateDirectory`. To build the path string, use `makepath`.

Comment: I'm currently on linux, but thanks, I'm normally working on windows. It looks useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either use the portable Boost.Filesystem Library which provides the function
[`create_directory`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#create_directory) or use the facilities your target environment provides, e.g. the POSIX function [`mkdir`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/mkdir.html) for Linux.

Boost also provides functionality to create a path, just look around in the reference to find what you need.

Using the `system` command is a bad idea.

---

If you and your professor are using MSVC 2015 or gcc5.3 or newer, you can probably use the experimental implementation of C++1z's [`create_directory`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/create_directory). It is based on Boost, but Boost is much wider supported.

Comment: Thanks. I know that boost is very good :) . But than if my professor wants to compile it, he will need boost ... . That's why I'm looking for something simple.

Comment: @Kvader There is no standard way, you either use something portable like Boost, some system dependent facility like POSIX or you wait until 2017 when C++ is supposed to get filesystem support. Actually, some very up-to-date compilers may already support this on an experimental basis, I will look it up.

Comment: I have gcc4.8.2 and I don't have administrative rights to upgrade. But yes [create_directory](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/create_directory) is good solution. (I hope at least safer). I'm looking forward to 2017! I hope that some boost features will be included to standard c++. Thank you very much for your answer. It's pity that there is no standard way so far. I consider boost as the best solution, but right now I have to do it this way.